# Find missing number between 1 to 100

Tags: c

This question has been asked here on SO before with below code

```
find3missing(int* array)
{ 
    int newarray[100] = {0};
    For i = 0 to 99  
        ++newarray[array[i]] ;
    For i = 0 to 99 
        If newarray[i] != 1
            Cout << “the missing number is ” << i+1 << endl ;
}
```

But when I checked this code, it doesn't seem to work. Suppose I have an array of {1,2,6}. The output should be 3,4,5 but with the code above I get 1,4,5,6 instead. Below is my implementation of pseudo code with array size 6.

```
main()
{
    int a[6]={1,2,6};
    int tmp[6]={0},i;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        ++tmp[a[i]];
    }
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        if(tmp[i]!=1)
        {
            printf("%d",i+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the right code?

Comment: That does not look like C code. And if it does not give you the correct answer, the algorithm is probably not correct (or you did something wrong).

Comment: The code is horrible. It isn't C... It isn't VB... It isn't even C++. It COULD be pseudo code :-)

Comment: Are you sure then that you have implemented it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `++newarray[array[i]]` should be `++newarray[array[i] - 1]`. This because you are interested in a sequence of 1-100 numbers, so no 0, but C arrays are 0 based. If you then look at the `cout`: `the missing number is ” << i+1` here you "unshift" the number by adding 1.

There is another problem: you should pass the number of elements of the `array`, something like:

```
find3missing(int* array, int length) { 
  int newarray[100] = {0};

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      ++newarray[array[i] - 1] ;
  }
```

Comment: But `i` seems to go from `0` to `99`.

Comment: Yes, but `array[0 - 1]` would give you an error or the last element (depending on the language ;)). Or am I missing the point? I'm not saying that the algorithm is correct (I think the second loop should start from `1` and `newarray` should be initialized with `100` elements), but that part seems to be ok.

Comment: @FelixKling You clearly are right, but history has cancelled my error :-) :-)

Comment: Ah that way makes more sense :)

Comment: ++newarray[array[i] - 1] Worked for me .

Answer (score 1):

C/C++ arrays are zero based, as `A[i]` is equivalent to `*(A+i)`. So change   `++newarray[array[i]]` to `++newarray[array[i]-1]`. Also use `malloc`, `free` and `memset` to use an array of dynamic size.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void find3missing(int* pArray, size_t size, int min, int max){
    int* newarray;
    int i;
    unsigned int j;
    int range = max - min;
    if(range < 0)
        return;
    newarray = (int*) malloc(range*sizeof(int)); // allocate enough memory
    memset(newarray,0,range*sizeof(int));        // set that block to zero
    for(j = 0; j < size; ++j){
        ++newarray[pArray[j]-min];
    }
    for(i = 0; i < range; ++i){
        if(!newarray[i])
            printf("%d is missing!\n",min+i);
    }
    free(newarray);
}

int main(){
    int test[] = {1,3,6};
    find3missing(test,sizeof(test)/sizeof(int),1,6);
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that this solution is very inefficient if your array is sorted. In this case have a look at [Jimmy Gustafsson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632592/1139697).

Answer (score 1):

This algoritm will be quite simple, since you're using a sorted array. Simply check if the current value +1 equals the nextvalue like below:

```
find3missing(){ 
  int array[arraySize]; // the array with integers

  for(i=0;i<arraySize;i++)
     if(array[i]+1 != array[i+1])  // if value array[i]+1 is not equal the next index 
                                   // value, then it's a missing number 
        printf("A missing number: %i", i+1); 
  }
```

Comment: well are you using c or c++? You tagged it as C but posted an example earlier in c++ code with cout :) i'll modify the answer to c code

Comment: for array {1,2,6} output comes out to be 3,4,5 but your example its coming 2,3,4,5,6